# How to empty a char array?

Tags: c, arrays, char

Have an array of chars like char members[255]. How can I empty it completely without using a loop?

```
char members[255];
```

By "empty" I mean that if it had some values stored in it then it should not. For example if I do strcat then old value should not remain

```
members = "old value";

//empty it efficiently
strcat(members,"new"); // should return only new and not "old value new"
```

Comment: What do you mean "empty an array"?

Comment: members[0]=members[1]=members[2]=members[3]...=members[255]=0  no loop there ;)

Comment: So your "array" is a special kind of array: it is a `string`. To "empty" a string, set it's first element to '\0': `members[0] = '\0';`

Comment: Community seems to be in favour of memset. But is that most efficient way given my requirements?

Comment: @Alex: Clearly not. Although the no-loop requirement looks like an overkill - what are you trying to avoid?

Comment: @Alex Xander: "Community" is clearly wrong in this case. There are situations that call for 'memset' (like wiping out data to prevent unauthorized use), but for the simple string reset (as in your case) the correct answer is to zero the first element only.

Answer (score 207, accepted):

using

```
  memset(members, 0, 255);
```

in general

```
  memset(members, 0, sizeof members);
```

if the array is in scope, or

```
  memset(members, 0, nMembers * (sizeof members[0]) );
```

if you only have the pointer value, and nMembers is the number of elements in the array.

---

EDIT Of course, now the requirement has changed from the generic task of clearing an array to purely resetting a string, `memset` is overkill and just zeroing the first element suffices (as noted in other answers).

---

EDIT In order to use *memset*, you have to **include string.h**.

Comment: +1 - I would go for this as it ensures that all array elements are in a known state.

Comment: It goes against the (epic) requirement of not using a loop, though.

Comment: While memset is probably not implemented as a recursion, it could be -- in either case, the iteration is decently hidden from sight, which was the ostensible requirement.

Answer (score 43):

Depends on what you mean by 'empty':

```
members[0] = '\0';
```

Comment: That would only change the value of members[0], not members[1] through members[254]. Fine if you are accessing sequentially...but not so fine in other cases.

Comment: After the OP's edit it seems my solution should work for his requirements, as strcat() will find the NULL byte and treat it accordingly.

Comment: nevertheless memset seems to be a better solution

Comment: Not a better solution. Just a solution to a different problem.

Comment: Alex Xander: memset is not the better solution, at least not in your case. As pointed by others, memset() will actually loop through the array, even if you don't actually see a "for" statement.

Comment: There is no need to use memset() when every known version of strcat() will handle NULL in the same way. In a similar, but simpler logic, why shred README files when they can just be deleted?

Comment: There's no way to "empty" an abstract array in C. Every array constains something, even if it is zeroes. The notion of "emptying an array" is only applicable to higher-level logical interpretations of array contents. For example, the contents of the array might be interpreted as a C-string. In that case the proper way to "empty" it is to set the very first element to '\0'. Exactly what Felix did. I don't know what other interpretations the OP might have in mind, but without making it more specific all those attempts with 'memset' are just meaningless answers to a meaningless question.

Comment: @tinkertim: There's no NULL here. And no, 'strcat' does not know how to handle NULL. It will crash if you pass NULL to it.

Answer (score 12):

Don't bother trying to zero-out your char array if you are dealing with strings. Below is a simple way to work with the char strings.

Copy (assign new string):

```
strcpy(members, "hello");
```

Concatenate (add the string):

```
strcat(members, " world");
```

Empty string:

```
members[0] = 0;
```

Simple like that.

Answer (score 8):

char members[255] = {0};

Comment: Nope, because he didn't specify that it must be done after initializing. Especially this may have been understood by his first example before edit and because it's also very common use case to clear an array.

Comment: I give you +2 as compensation that he gave you -1 :P :D

Answer (score 5):

***EDIT:*** Given the most recent edit to the question, this will no longer work as there is no null termination - if you tried to print the array, you would get your characters followed by a number of non-human-readable characters. However, I'm leaving this answer here as community wiki for posterity.

```
char members[255] = { 0 };
```

That should work. According to the C Programming Language:

> If the array has fixed size, the number of initializers may not exceed the number of members of the array; if there are fewer, the remaining members are initialized with 0.

This means that every element of the array will have a value of 0. I'm not sure if that is what you would consider "empty" or not, since 0 is a valid value for a `char`.

Comment: It depends on how you define "empty". The char with a value of 0 is not a human-readable character and the array of chars is in a known state. I would consider that empty. It also does the exact same thing as memset (if my recollection of memset is correct - it's been too long since I've used C).

Answer (score 4):

You cannot empty an array as such, it always contains the same amount of data.

In a bigger context the data in the array may represent an empty list of items, but that has to be defined in addition to the array. The most common ways to do this is to keep a count of valid items (see the answer by pmg) or for strings to terminate them with a zero character (the answer by Felix). There are also more complicated ways, for example a ring buffer uses two indices for the positions where data is added and removed.

Answer (score 4):

Use `bzero(array name, no.of bytes to be cleared);`

Answer (score 3):

```
members[0] = 0;
```

is enough, given your requirements.

Notice however this is not "emptying" the buffer. The memory is still allocated, valid character values may still exist in it, and so forth..

Comment: Can be also written as *members = 0;

Comment: Even `0` is a valid character. We do not know if `members` are treated as C string or not.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with

```
members_in_use = 0;
```

Comment: It actually makes a lot of sense, since the OP is asking for an operation (emptying) that is not part of a C array - therefore, ideally, he'd implement a new data structure, and pmg's way of signaling the structure is empty is good enough.

Comment: No, it really doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Kinopiko: Apparently you don't understand the approach then

Comment: Kinopiko: read starblue answer as it explains my reasoning better than I can explain in a comment (thank you starblue)

Comment: Hmm, this is an interesting approach, will members_in_use still be an array? Can I later do a; member_in_use[5] = value?
Is this equivalent to memset(members_in_use, 0, 255); as Steve stated? If so, why use one instead of the other?

Comment: @BenMezger: no, you misunderstand my answer. An array of 255 elements will always have 255 elements. There is no way to make it have less elements. My answer uses a helper variable to indicate how many of those elements are "valid".

Answer (score 1):

By "empty an array" if you mean reset to 0, then you can use bzero.

```
#include <strings.h>  
void bzero(void *s, size_t n);
```

If you want to fill the array with some other default character then you may use memset function.

```
#include <string.h>  
void *memset(void *s, int c, size_t n);
```

Comment: bzero and memset (usually) both use a loop.

Answer (score 1):

In this case just `members[0] = 0` works.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer:** I don't usually program in C so there may be any syntax gotcha in my examples, but I hope the ideas I try to express are clear.

If "emptying" means "containing an empty string", you can just assign the first array item to zero, which will effectively make the array to contain an empry string:

```
members[0] = 0;
```

If "emptying" means "freeing the memory it is using", you should not use a fixed char array in the first place. Rather, you should define a pointer to char, and then do malloc / free (or string assignment) as appropriate.

An example using only static strings:

```
char* emptyString="";
char* members;

//Set string value
members = "old value";

//Empty string value
member = emptyString

//Will return just "new"
strcat(members,"new");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following instruction:

```
strcpy_s(members, "");
```