# How do I make an array empty in C?

Tags: c, arrays, initialization

I am trying to make an empty array. Here is my code:

```
if(n == 0 || n == 1)
{
    factors[] = {};
}
```

However, it says that it expects an expression inside of [] and {}. What is the correct syntax to do such a thing?

Comment: What do you mean by "empty" array?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to empty a char array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559487/how-to-empty-a-char-array)

Comment: What do you mean by "empty" array? In C arrays have a defined size unlike scripting languages. It looks like you need to figure out the fundamentals

Comment: @MrJLP As per my instructor: Should you be given the input 0 or 1, return an empty list (i.e., a list with length zero).

Comment: Your comment indicates this is an [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why not ask and provide details about what you are trying to accomplish, instead of what you think is the way to do it?

Comment: Return an "empty list" or an "empty array"? Yes, describe the problem you have first

Comment: @StoryTeller Well, my instructor said Should you be given the input 0 or 1, return an empty list (i.e., a list with length zero).

Comment: @JerseyFonseca - I have no idea what you should return from where. Provide details in the post, not in comments. And if you need to implement a certain behavior, give the skeleton of this behavior. It's up to you to explain yourself well, not to us to divine what you mean from obscure comments about what you instructor said.

Comment: @JerseyFonseca - You said: `my instructor said Should you be given the input 0 or 1, return an empty list`. Notice that `list` and `array` are typically different things. `list` normally refers to some sort of `linked list`. A list can be empty (aka `head == NULL`). An array can not. So maybe you misunderstood your assignment by using `array`.

Comment: You want to initialize the array with zero?

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR** You cannot because the requirement is invalid from C point of view. Array sizes are fixed and cannot grow or shrink whatever be the *usage requirement*.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.7.6.2, *Array declarators* (*emphasis mine*)

> In addition to optional type qualifiers and the keyword static, the `[` and `]` may delimit
>   **an expression or `*`**. If they delimit an expression (which specifies the size of an array), the
>   expression shall have an integer type. If the expression is a constant expression, it shall
>   have a value greater than zero. [...]

Also, as per the Initialization syntax, C11, chapter §6.7.9, the brace closed initializer list should have at minimum one initializer element (object). An initializer in form of `{ };` is invalid C.

---

Note:

If you meant *"How do I make the contents of an array empty in C?"*, well, in that case, assuming "empty" translates to a value of `0`, we can use `memset()` or a loop-and-assignment to get that done. This, however, makes the array contents empty, not the size of the array.

Answer (score 3):

Try executing these two cases, so that you can understand what's actually going on with gcc.

CASE 1:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
 int arr[]={};
 printf("size:%d\n",sizeof(arr));
}
```

CASE 2:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
 int arr[]={};
 arr[0]=100;
 printf("size:%d\n%d\n",sizeof(arr),arr[0]);
}
```

This is because name of an array represents the address of base element. Also, if you declare an array with particular size, you cannot define the boundaries and you can access memory even out of boundaries till the segment in which the array is declared exhausts out of memory.

Coming to your code `factors[] = {};`, you cannot do this because this is not declaration of the array factors, though you are trying to assign no values using the {} construct. You can leave the [] empty only when you are initializing the array.

Comment: Do you know `int arr[]={};` is actually invalid in ISO C?

Comment: According to the standards, `int arr[]={};` is invalid (only in theory). But practically, this is valid and possible. If you have executed the two cases I've mentioned in the answer, you will understand this clearly.

Comment: the validity depends on your compiler, there's nothing that guarantees the correctness of the code.

Comment: Of course! As far as gcc 6.3.0 and earlier versions are concerned, this construct works smoothly. I have no idea about other compilers like TCC etc.

Comment: Thanks much for the valuable insights!! However, [my compilation failed](https://godbolt.org/g/3Wkw3G), so I cannot run the code snippet you provided and thus failing to understand anything. Halp?

Comment: In the link that you have provided, please remove all the switches `--pedantic -Wextra -Werror -Wall` in compiler options section. These switches helps performing tight compilation i.e., all the warnings are considered as errors and complete platform independent code.

Comment: Thanks, I'll let that advice pass. :)

Comment: This doesn't compile at all with GCC configured to be a C compiler. If you configure GCC to be a something-else compiler, then any random crap might of course compile. This question is tagged C and it is not tagged GCC. Nothing in the question indicates that GCC is used.

Comment: May be, you need some intro to compiling a C program. You can find lot of reference on the internet. Practice them first and then try executing this, so that you don't land into your own crap anymore! :)

Comment: @Lundin It's both funny and surprising how some people intentionally ignore good suggestions. :)

Comment: @surendranath It is quite easy. GCC is per default set to compile either against the non-standard "gnu90" or against the non-standard "gnu11", depending on if it is older or newer than GCC version 5.0. If you want it to be a comforming C compiler, you must compile the code as `gcc -std=c11 -pedantic-errors`, where -std=c11 is the current C standard and pedantic-errors means "actually compile according to the requirements of the standard". If you do not set these, you are not using GCC as a standard C compiler, period.

Answer (score 1):

Technically you *can't* make an array empty. An array will have a fixed size that you can not change.

If you want to *reset* the *values* in the array, either copy from another array with default values, or loop over the array and reset each value.

Comment: Why can't you make an array with a fixed size of 0?

Comment: @endolith No, C doesn't allow it. An array much have a non-zero positive size (with the only exception being [a flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member)).

Answer (score 0):

You can't free the memory of array, because it is fixed. you can set some default values like '0' using memset function.

void *memset(void *arrptr, int value, size_t n);

The expressions [] & {} can be used at the time of declaration of array